# How to invoke Geo commands with Lettuce's and Redis asynchronously

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I am trying to use lettuce in order to add geolocations to Redis.
I managed to do it using the sync methods.

Is it possible to convert this logic using the async api for lettue?

sync code:

```
StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection= client.connect();
RedisCommands syncCommands=syncCommands = connection.sync()
long result = syncCommands.geoadd(key, longitude, latitude, userId);
```

How do you convert this into an async invocation?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection= client.connect();
RedisAsyncCommands<String, String> asyncCommands = connection.async()
RedisFuture<Long> result = asyncCommands.geoadd(key, longitude, latitude, userId);
```

lettuce 4.0 allows to use different APIs with on one connection (synchronous, asynchronous and reactive). That's different to lettuce 3.x where the API style was coupled with the connection.

Just call the `async()` method on the connection object to obtain the asynchronous API. You can find more about the asynchronous API [in the Wiki](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/wiki/Asynchronous-API-(4.0)#creating-futures-using-lettuce).

Comment: When expecting to have stable release of lettuce 4?:)

Comment: End of September/Start of October